# customizng link using css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a link with the following format:

```
        a:link
    {
        color: #034af3;
        }

    a:editedLink
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

along with the above I want to have a link with the following and I want to use both of them in my page depending upon my requirement.
How can I do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

There are some pseudo classes in css for links

they are

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Pseudo-classes can be combined with CSS classes like

```
a.red:visited {color:#FF0000;}
<a class="red" href="css_syntax.asp">CSS Syntax</a>
```

If this is not you want ,pls explain a bit further

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `:whateverYouLike`.

`:link, :visited, :hover, :active` ar reserved css pseudo classes/selectors.

If you want your own styling, use css classes. Like:

```
<a href="#" class="editedLink">LinkText</a>
```

plus css definition:

```
.editedLink {color:#FFF;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
    color: #034af3;
}

a.editedLink{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

<a href="/link" class="editedLink">Text</a>
<a href="/link">Text</a>
```